# Error in XML- unbounded prefix

Tags: android

Can anyone explain why I get this error here?
Here is my styles.xml in the res/layout folder

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    </style>


   <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/LightGrey</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
        <padding 
            android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 
    </style>

</resources>
```

The error seems to occur in the padding section in ButtonTheme

Comment: there is no namespace for android. You can have `<item name="android:padding">1dp</item>`

Comment: I think problem in the padding line, its not the way to define the padding like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the namespace declaration.
try inserting `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` into `<resources>`

i.e.

`<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use android prefix namespace for eg:- android:name="AppBaseTheme"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style
         android:name="AppBaseTheme"
         android:parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Comment: There is no need to define the     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> in the style.xml file, Have you checked you answer, working some where before posting here?

Answer (score 0):

You should to use

```
<item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
```

instead of

```
<padding 
        android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

you were missing the schema uri and the padding was not formatted properly.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/LightGrey</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```